# UIAlertView throws alert "Expression result unused"

Tags: expression, alert, uialertview

I know, that similar questions have already been asked. But I got the same problem now and have been trying for hours to get rid of it. None of the solutions helped. And it´s working.

I got “Expression result unused” in the second line.

Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [UIAlertView new];

        [myAlertView initWithTitle:@"Bitte beachten…"  //Alertsign is shown here
                           message:@"Ihre Lösung hat leider noch Fehler!"
                          delegate:self
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen"
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

[myAlertView show];
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is **wrong brackets settings**.
This is correct:

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView new]
            [initWithTitle:@"Bitte beachten…"
               message:@"Ihre Lösung hat leider noch Fehler!"
              delegate:self
     cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen"
     otherButtonTitles:nil];

[myAlertView show];
```